# Are Microsoft Logic App and Workflow same

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Are these two the same:

- https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.EmptyWorkflow and
- https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.LogicApp

I followed two different tutorials to create logic apps and I get there. Is that the workflows are renamed to logic apps?

Comment: Can you please help us with the tutorials that you followed?

Comment: Here it is.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y74fh8rB4LA. As I was trying to follow the video and trying various ways, I got that doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.EmptyWorkflow seems to be an outdated link for consumption Logic Apps.

https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.LogicApp can be used to create both consumption and standard Logic Apps.

Different types are reviewed in this article: [Single-tenant versus multi-tenant and integration service environment for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare)

The #create links are normally not used directly. They are opened when `+ Create a resource` or `+ Add` links are clicked in Azure Portal.